# Php laravel - page only shows white after login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

My registration page works well. As I registered a new account, it then redirects me to the "home" page. However, when I tried to login, it redirects me to a blank white page. I tried to check the *route*, the *action="login"* on the form, at the *controller*, it all corrects. I tried different way of writing the code such as *Auth::Attempt* as well as *auth()->attempt()*. I compared it with the *register* page that I've created. It should be fine. I really have no idea where I did wrong. Please help. I need to complete a project by next week tuesday. I'm in a very tight schedule right now.

Route code

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Route::get('/record', function () {
    return view('record');
});

Route::get('/profile', function () {
    return view('profile');
});

Route::get('register', [RegisterController::class, 'create'])->middleware('guest');
Route::post('register', [RegisterController::class, 'store'])->middleware('guest');

Route::get('login', [SessionsController::class, 'create'])->middleware('guest');
Route::post('session', [SessionsController::class, 'store'])->middleware('guest');

Route::post('logout', [SessionsController::class, 'destroy'])->middleware('auth');
```

Controller page

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SessionsController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('sessions.create');
    }


    public function store()
    {
        $attributes = request()->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (Auth::Attempt($attributes)) {
            return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Your account has been created.');
        }
    }

    public function destroy()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        redirect('/')->with('success', 'Goodbye');
    }
}
```

Home page

```
<x-layout>
    <div id="sidebar" class="bg-gray-100 border border-black border-opacity-5 w-96 py-8 px-8 mt-16 text-white">
        <div class="relative flex lg:inline-flex items-center border border-gray-400 rounded-l px-3 py-3 text-white">
            <form method="GET" action="/">
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Staff" class="bg-transparent placeholder-gray font-semibold text-sm" value="{{ request('search') }}">
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="relative lg:inline-flex bg-gray-100 rounded-xl">
            <x-category-dropdown />
        </div>
    </div>
</x-layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely cause of this is that your `Auth::attempt()` is failing. You have no fallback/default response if it fails:

```
// redirect ONLY IF authentication succeeds
if (Auth::Attempt($attributes)) {
    return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Your account has been created.');
}

// we get here if authentication fails, but do nothing
```

Add in a fallback redirect for instances where authentication fails:

```
if (Auth::Attempt($attributes)) {
    return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Your account has been created.');
}

return redirect('/')->with('errors', 'Authentication failed.');
```

Comment: I tried adding an 'else'  and return 'any string' . yeah indeed it fails. the email and password required to login is correct as i see on the database. the request and validate that I use here is the same as the one used in registered. hmm...

Comment: @jabs93 Glad it’s no longer showing a blank page. Your authentication failing is an entirely separate issue however.

Comment: are there any possible causes that i could look into further ? this problem has made me want to pull my hair for days :|

Comment: @jabs93  Yes. Firstly use [Fortify](https://github.com/laravel/fortify) rather than rolling your own authentication framework. Pointless reinventing the wheel and there’s a community of people improving it, rather than just you. If you really don’t want to do that (which I highly suggest you do!), create a new question with your registration logic. It’s a separate issue and so requires a separate question.

Comment: i want to do that but i'm in a tight schedule (i have to complete a project by tuesday). i may have to go with asking a new question

Comment: @jabs93 Fortify would be quick to implement as you only need to build the UI. Good luck with your timeline, we all know that feeling!

Comment: @jabs93 Additionally, please mark my answer as accepted if it has solved this particular issue.